# Multi Band Infragistics UltraGrid Row Select problem

Tags: crash, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am bringing in data from SQL that is to be displayed in a multi band ultragrid. This works great. It does what it is supposed to in this regard; however, if I try to select a row other than the first one, in any band of the bands, it freezes the program.

When the grid is loaded, the first row seems to be active (text is bold), so I tried doing an update on the active row. This got rid of the active row, but didn't fix the problem.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Some questions to aide in troubleshooting... How are you binding to the datasource? What type of object are you using for your datasource? Are you able to replicate this problem using another ultragrid/datasource?

Comment: Can you post some code?  Have you tried debugging?  When you 'break all' - which line of code is stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `BindingList<>` as your data source? Try converting to `List<>`.If you have to use BindingList<> then set the SyncWithCurrencyManager property on ultragrid to false.  This tells the grid not to synchronize the current row with the current position of the CurrencyManager

Comment: I'm using BIndingList<> and setting SyncWithCurrencyManager to false just saved my week.  I wish I could accept on behalf of the OP.